# How can I retrieve cookies for webserver A when my project is deployed on webserver B?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

The project is multiple modules, each of them is deployed to a separate webserver. All of them on the same mainframe. (same IP address)

I have a main menu where I login and then list all the available modules on all servers. From here I can click and go to any of them modules.

I send cookies in the response (when logging in, say Server A), then on Server B (one of the modules) when I want to go back to the main menu, I check the cookies to see if the user is logged in.

The problem is, Server B isn't seeing cookies generated by Server A. So each time I return to main menu, the user will be logged out.

Is there anyway to store cookies to be used by multiple virtual webservers (on same IP) or any other idea?

Comment: Does the cookie include a path or domain part? If yes, do they match Server B?

Comment: @Dominik, the problem is I'm not sure how the mainframe manage servers. In the browser they all seem to work on the same IP address, but the mainframe admin says they are on different virtual servers.

Comment: Is the problem, that the browser does not send the cookie, or that server b does not read it? Could you provide a sample of the cookie and its parameters (domain, path, port, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the domain-name in the cookie with the correct value, it should work:

i.E. Domainname in cookie: **".host.com"**

The cookie will be sent to following hosts: **"server1.host.com"**, **"server2.host.com"** ....

Comment: Domain name isn't set, path is set to "/". And since all applications are deployed to the same physical machine I suppose the root path should work, no?

Comment: If you do not set the domain for the cookie it will be set with an default value, if I remember correctly the full hostname. By default, cookies are only returned to the server that sent them.

You can also set a path, which is an additional criteria for the browser to decide if he has to send a cookie or not.

i.e. Cookies for domain.com/images and domain.com/files are different - the domain is equal, but the path is different.